# Populate RecyclerView using Sugar ORM

Tags: android, android-recyclerview, sugarorm

This is what I have right now it gets the right number of items but it displays the column name. Not the individual cell names. For Example I'll have 3 entries in the database(I checked and it worked fine). Then when I try to populate the `RecyclerView` all I get is 3 entries that say name;

My adapter:

```
public class RecyclerViewAdapter extends RecyclerView.Adapter{

private List<Session> sessionLists;
private static Context sContext;

public RecyclerViewAdapter(List<Session> sessionLists){
    this.sessionLists = sessionLists;
}

@Override
public RecyclerView.ViewHolder onCreateViewHolder(ViewGroup viewGroup, int viewType) {

    View layoutView = LayoutInflater
            .from(viewGroup.getContext())
            .inflate(R.layout.item_row, null);
    return new MyViewHolder(layoutView);
}

@Override
public void onBindViewHolder(RecyclerView.ViewHolder viewHolder, int position) {

    Session sessionList = sessionLists.get(position);
    MyViewHolder myViewHolder = (MyViewHolder) viewHolder;
}

@Override
public int getItemCount() {
    return sessionLists.size();
}

/** This is our ViewHolder class */
public static class MyViewHolder extends RecyclerView.ViewHolder {

    public TextView tvSessionName;
    public TextView tvSessionDate;
    public TextView tvArrowsShot;

    public MyViewHolder(View itemView) {
        super(itemView); // Must call super() first
        tvSessionName = (TextView) itemView.findViewById(R.id.tvSessionName);
        tvSessionDate = (TextView) itemView.findViewById(R.id.tvSessionDate);
        tvArrowsShot = (TextView) itemView.findViewById(R.id.tvArrowsShot);
    }
}
}
```

This is my Session.java for `Sugar ORM`:

```
public class Session extends SugarRecord<Session> {
String date, name;

public Session(){
}

public Session(String date, String name){
    this.date = date;
    this.name = name;
}

public String[] getSession(){
    return new String[]{date, name};
}

public String toString(){
    return date;
}
}
```

This is how I am calling it in the main activity:

```
List<Session> sessionList = Session.listAll(Session.class);
                    RecyclerViewAdapter adapter = new RecyclerViewAdapter(sessionList);
                    recyclerView.setAdapter(adapter);
```

Answer (score 1):

Well, me not thinking forgot to set the `TextViews`. If you wondering I forgot

`myViewHolder.tvSessionName.setText(sessionLists.get(position).toString());` inside `onBindViewHolder`

I believe this is the correct way to do this. If not people inform me.